# IJulia plot not displayed in browser

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, julia

I'm now playing around with IJulia and have just tried to do the same thing as does [this tutorial](https://github.com/stevengj/julia-mit/blob/master/README.md) in MIT's course Github page using IJulia (I'm not a MIT student, but I'm sure it's irrelevant here), but when I tried to plot the graph, there are no graph depicted in the screen and instead just  
`Out[3]:
PyObject <matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x1185edf10>` shown up. In IPython notebook, you can avoid this issue by starting the notebook via `ipython notebook --pylab inline`. However, it looks like there are no such arguments required in IJulia notebook, since it is assumed to plot those graphs inline at default.

So why does it not displayed in my browser? And how can I fix it?

I'm on OS X 10.9 and Julia 0.2.0, and every other functionalities related to Julia and IJulia work well as far as I know.

Thanks.

Comment: Might be this bug: https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/issues/94  ... Can you try a different browser?

Comment: Tried on Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Opera, but it didn't work on any browsers.

Comment: Make sure you are actually running IJulia: try something like `rand(10)` that is not in the default pyhon namespace, or conversely `import sys`. If there is a problem with IJulia installation, you might actually be starting python underneath (which would lead to no-show b/c ipython wasn't started with `--pylab inline`). If this is not the problem, then I would suggest to file a bug against IJulia on github: ttps://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/issues

Comment: Yeah, I was running IJulia. Thanks for the suggestion - I would file a bug against the dev-team at some point.